# Increase line spacing around inline maths (opposite of smash/strut) / Add padding around inline maths

Tags: spacing, amsmath, inline, strut

Very simply, inline maths (particularly display style) doesn't offer much padding between lines. I know that there has been a lot of commentary on using commands such as `\smash` and `\strut` to do the opposite (remove spacing), but how would one go about *increasing* the spacing around maths elements inline.

[image]

For example above

```
Whole numbers can also be written as a fraction to make their multiplication easier. Any whole number, for example `3' can be written as $\dfrac{3}{1}$. That is, we simply put the whole number we want as the numerator, and the denominator just becomes 1.
```

(1) Ideally, would be good to be able to universally fix this with a single command; but failing this

(2) Is it possible to simply provide padding around such maths elements (even a phantom box) to achieve the desired result?

Comment: `\usepackage{stackengine}` then `\addstackgap{$\dfrac{3}{1}$}` will add by default 3pt above and below the argument.  Default can be changed with optional argument or else via `\setstackgap{S}{<length>}`

Comment: Please clarify the use case you have in mind. At the moment, your query sounds very much for a request for guidance on how to shoot yourself in the foot, typographically speaking. However, that’s probably not your objective, is it? Hence the request for clarification as to what you’re trying to achieve. Please also state the line spacing that’s in effect in your document.

Comment: @Mico, I just want to be able to add padding to maths elements inline. Steven's answer works well however